# RegEx conversion to use with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm currently using this RegEx `^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(19|2[0-1])\d{2}$` in .NET to validate a field with Month and Year (`12/2000`).

I'm changing all my RegEx validations to JavaScript and I'm facing an issue with this one because of `/`in the middle which I'm having problems escaping.

So based on other answers in SO I tried:

```
    RegExp.quote = function (str) {
        return (str + '').replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
    };
    var reDOB = '^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(19|2[0-1])\d{2}$'

            var re = new RegExp(RegExp.quote(reDOB));
            if (!re.test(args.Value)) {
                args.IsValid = false;
                return;
            }
```

However, validations fails even with valid data.

Comment: How about just a simple `var re = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|2[0-1])\d{2}$/;` which uses the regex operator `//` ??

Comment: @sln Isn't that a _regex literal_?

Comment: Oh, maybe. Doesn't it compile `re` there as a regex object ?

Comment: Sort of like a variant maybe `var re = /.../;` regex object, as opposed to `var s = '...';` bstr object.

Comment: I would had swear I had tried /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|2[0-1])\d{2}$/ already, but I was mistaken. I tried 'again' now that you mention and it work. Thanks!

Question, what would you change in expression so month could be one digit as opposed to two?

Also, do answer the question so I can mark it!

Comment: @Diomedes—for single digit months, remove the leading zero: `/^([1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|2[0-1])\d{2}$/`

Comment: This doesn’t work because you’re using a function to escape plain text for use in a regular expression when what you actually have is a regular expression. Just plain `new RegExp(reDOB)` would have worked. (But yes, the literal is better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `^` of first and `$` from end of regex pattern. And add `\` before any character which you want to match by pattern. so pattern is like this:

`(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(19|2[0-1])\d{2}`

You can test your regex from [here](http://www.regexr.com/)